# Singular points in nonlinear systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose, for example, that I have the following non-linear system of ODE's;

$$(y^2-y'^2)g+y' y g=P$$
$$y'(y' g''+(y''+y)g')=S,$$

where $y,g,P,S$ are all functions of the dependent variable $x$. How can I find the possible singular points of this system, i.e. points where $y$ and $g$ might diverge?

For example, in the linear equation

$$y''+a(x) y' +b(x)y=0$$

these points would be the poles of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. What's the case for non-linear equations?

Comment: Your example system has to be classified as DAE, a system of differential-algebraic equations, as one can not solve directly for both highest order derivatives. You need to form the derivative of the first equation for that to become possible. For DAE there are more possibilities of singular or otherwise non-regular points. // In general, singular is the opposite of regular, apart from singularities of the function in general, points of the time-state domain are singular if the order of the equation reduces in these points.

Comment: By taking the derivative of the first equation, I can then indeed solve for $y''$ and $g''$. Would it be correct to say that potential irregularities occur when the denominators of $y''$ and $g''$ vanish?

Comment: Yes, or in the divisor-free version the coefficients of one of the derivatives would vanish, reducing the order at that point/surface.